# What does "if any details about him" mean?

Tags: meaning

> However, just searching the website would not give many, **if any
>   details about him** and would not include any personal information she
>   could use to impersonate the target.

The above sentence seems incomplete because of the bold part. Does this sentence mean:

> However, just searching the website would not give many information,
>   **even if there is any details about him**. And searching the website
>   would not include ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A missing comma has caused you to misparse the sentence. It should be:

> However, just searching the website would not give **many, if any,** details about him ...

Here, "not ... many, if any" means few or possibly none.

Answer (score 0):

Some punctuation is missing from your quoted text. It should be:

> just searching the website would not give many, if any, details about
>   him

There should be a comma after 'any'. This makes 'if any' a parenthetical clause, meaning 'if any details at all exist'. The commas before 'if' and after 'any' are called parenthical commas, and, as their name implies, may be replaced with parentheses.